# Servlet not available - HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, ejb

I am new to EJB and trying to develop a Currency Converter application in EJB..In my index.jsp page, I am inputting the amount(in Dollar) and the currency to which it is to be converted abd sending it to a servlet page Convert.java where it needs to fetch the convertion from my database table by matching the inputted currency with the help of my entity class currency..
When I run click on the button on my JSP page, I am getting the following error

```
HTTP Status 404 - Servlet Convert is not available

type Status report

messageServlet Convert is not available

descriptionThe requested resource (Servlet Convert is not available) is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
```

Here is the code for my index.jsp

```
<body>
    <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
    <form action="Convert" method="get">
        Enter Amount In Dollar <input type="text" name="amt"/>
        Enter Currency <input type="text" name="curr"/>
        <input type="submit" name="conv" value="Convert"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

The code for my servlet page Convert.java is as follows :

```
 public class Convert extends HttpServlet {
@EJB
private currencyFacade cf1;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        String curr;
        curr=request.getParameter("curr");
        Long cv =null,fin,amt;
        amt=Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("amt"));
        currency c1=new currency();
        List s=cf1.findAll();
        for (Iterator it = s.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {

           currency ac1 = (currency) it.next();
           if(curr.equals(ac1.getCurrto()))
           {
               cv=c1.getValue();
        }}
        fin=amt*cv;
        out.println("Value of "+amt + "Dolar is " + fin+" "+curr);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        out.println("Error " + ex);
    }
}
```

Here is my entity class currency.java

```
@Entity
public class currency implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String currto;
private Long value;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getCurrto() {
    return currto;
}

public void setCurrto(String currto) {
    this.currto = currto;
}

public Long getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Long value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof currency)) {
        return false;
    }
    currency other = (currency) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entity.currency[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}

My web.xml file is as follows :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Convert</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Convert</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addcur</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>addcur</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Convert</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Convert</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addcur</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addcur</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Could you print your web.xml file?

Comment: use fully qualified name of class `Convert` at ``<servlet-class>Convert</servlet-class>``

Comment: Look at the sample code `Hello World` that I shared you.

Comment: What container and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Where have you bind the Servlet `Convert` with an URL pattern?

How HTML know about the Servlet class?

---

**Find a sample code on [The Hello World Java EE application](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_and_running_a_Java_EE_Hello_World_application) .**

---

Try with

```
@WebServlet("/Convert")
public class Convert extends HttpServlet {
   // ...
}
```

or try

```
@WebServlet(name = "ConvertServlet", urlPatterns = "/Convert")
public class Convert extends HttpServlet {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried both suggestions but in vain..the result is still same

Comment: What about fully qualified name of class Convert in `<servlet-class>Convert</servlet-class>`? have you read the sample code.

Comment: Have you read the Hello world sample code mentioned in my post as link?